# Convert coordinates to pixels on screen (and back again)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

**This is what I'm doing:**
Clicking a marker on the map to open a side panel and center the map on the 
marker. The side panel takes up 3/4 of the right side of the screen.

**This is what I need to happen:**
Center the marker according to the 1/4 of the viewport that is left after the panel opens.

I can get the pixel coordinates of the marker and do the calculations of where it needs to translate to while the panel is animating open. The problem is that [`flyTo()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#flyTo) only accepts [`LngLatLike`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#LngLatLike) objects and I cannot convert my pixel coordinates to latitude and longitude. Leaflet.js has a function called [`containerPointToLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-containerpointtolatlng) that came in handy before I switched to Mapbox GL.

Given the sofistication of Mapbox GL, despite its newness, I can only imagine this is a possibility. *But how?*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [project](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#project) and [unproject](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#unproject) methods make a lot of logic like this possible. If you have a click at a certain lngLat, and you want to position the map such that that geographic position is centered horizontally and at the 1/8 mark, you could:

1. Take the geographic position and turn it into a pixel position with `project`
2. Shift that pixel position right by (1/2-1/8) = 4/8-1/8 = 3/8 = `0.375 * map._containerDimensions()[0]`, by adding that number to it
3. Turn that shifted pixel position back into a geographic position with `unproject`

Or, you might also be able to do it the easy way by using the [offset option](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#AnimationOptions) in your `flyTo` call.

Comment: Aha! I `project` and `unproject` are exactly what I was looking for.

That worked, but I now realize I failed to mention that I am zooming in to a fixed zoom point during the `flyTo`, this only works when I stay at the same zoom level. Any idea how to accommodate for that?

Comment: Just add a `zoom` property to your options object. [Docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#flyto).  I like the use of [offset](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#animationoptions) here as its doing the calculation for you -- just pass in a [PointLike](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#pointlike) value [x, y].

Answer (score 4):

MapBox now has an [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/offset-vanishing-point-with-padding/) of how to do this on their site, using the `padding` option (though `offset` could work just as well).

Answer (score -1):

I'm in a similar situation, only my side-nav menu is 400px (same principal).
I encounter the same 2 obstacles:

1. Calculating the correction from pixels to lat/lng for the flyto function
2. Correcting for different zoom levels

@tmcw answer did an amazing job for the first one, but unfortunately I the [offset option in flyto function](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#flyto) is no longer available.

It figures that in order to get linear ratio between different zoom levels you need to divide 2<sup>zoom1</sup>:2<sup>zoom2</sup> according to the [docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/).

Full example:

```
// Desired zoom level at the end of flyTo
const zoomLevel = 16;
const zoomCorrection = Math.pow(2, this.map.getZoom()) / Math.pow(2, zoomLevel);

// Desired left shift/offset in px at the end of the flyTo. Use minus for right shift.
const leftShift = 200;


const lat = SelectedMarker.longitude;
const lng = SelectedMarker.latitude;
const coordinates = this.map.project([lat, lng]);
const offsetcoordinates = this.map.unproject([coordinates.x + (leftShift * zoomCorrection), coordinates.y]);

this.map.flyTo({
  animate: true,
  zoom: zoomLevel,
  center: [offsetcoordinates.lng, offsetcoordinates.lat],
});
```

Comment: You're making this too hard for yourself. An offset CAN be applied to flyTo() via [AnimationOptions](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/properties/#animationoptions)